# Using a SwiftUI menu in the top-trailing corner

Tags: swiftui

When placing a SwiftUI Menu button in the top-trailing corner, using ignoresSafeArea(), it works correctly in the SwiftUI preview:

[image: Close]

But not on the actual device/in simulator:

[image]

When I use ignoresSafeArea() again on the menu itself, a strange behavior occurs (iOS 14.5): without padding the menu looses function, with padding, the button moves down when the Menu appears and the Menu will have an odd spacing between button and Menu:

[image]

Is there a way to get a Menu to appear correctly in the top-trailing corner?

Example code:

```swift
struct MenuButtonExampleView: View {

    var body: some View {
        Color.yellow
            .ignoresSafeArea()
            .overlay(self.menuButton, alignment: .topTrailing)
    }

    @ViewBuilder var menuButton: some View {
        Menu(
            content: {
                Button(
                    action: {
                        debugPrint("Action")
                    },
                    label: {
                        Label("Action", systemImage: "xmark")
                    }
                )

            },
            label: {
                Button(
                    action: {},
                    label: {
                        ZStack {
                            Circle()
                                .foregroundColor(.green)
                                .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                            Image(systemName: "ellipsis")
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                        }
                    }
                )
                .padding(20)
            }
        )
    }

}
```

Comment: Works fine here Xcode 12.5 / iOS 14.5.

Comment: That's super strange. For me it only works in the SwiftUI preview, but it gets the safe area applied on iPhone 12 simulator and iPhone X device. Does the button look like the first screenshot (no padding on the top) on a device with notch for you?

Answer (score 1):

This may be due to the navigation bar.
You can try to add this code.

```
.navigationBarHidden(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a **let** constant and get the complete screen height and assign it to that constant and after that change the **body** code as you can see in the code below and it will work for every device

```
let customHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
    var body: some View {
        Color.yellow
            .overlay(self.menuButton, alignment: .topTrailing)
            .statusBar(hidden: true)
            .frame(height: customHeight + (customHeight/18))
            .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
```